# Assembly language to learn C/C++ languages

Tags: c++, c, assembly

Actualy i'd like to learn Assembly language to have a deep understanding of low-level operations to be able to write more efficient programs and be able to read and understand disassembled programs. But i'm confused on how to learn this language.

I have found a book called "The art of assembly language". The problem is that this book introducing something called "High Level Assambly Language".

Is that what i'm looking for, or it's just like any other high level programming language?

What is the difference bitween high-level and low-level assambly language?

Is there any thing to improve my experience?

Comment: IIRC, the first chapter of the book explains this. TL;DR it's asm with some high-level features to make programming easier.

Comment: `But i'm confused on how to learn this language.` - "Assembly" isn't a language, it's tied to an architecture... so you could say you want to learn "x86 assembly" for example. You should start by picking a single platform to learn from, like a classic 6502 processor

Comment: @Mike I'd just recommend a modern instruction (sub)set right away.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language might be worth a read for a condensed intro. Assuming you want X86 assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid HLA in my opinion, you aren't going to learn that much. The book is awesome though, I have learned assembly with that and the 16 bit assembler TASM, then switched to 32 bit when I felt comfortable doing so.
One thing I found helpful was to code something in C and watch the assembly generated by the compiler ( gcc -s) Just like everything else related to programming it's just a matter of practice. You will also find the series "write great code", by the same author, a very interesting reading.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitly not like any high level languages.

What I did that really helped me was to start writing simple C programs and compile them with `gcc -s`, which gives you the assembly for the code you are trying to compile, and try to understand how my C was transformed into this assembly output.

It's a really cool thing to do, with the gelp of ref books, obviously. Then, you can make modifications to your assembly code, and see the effects. And once that makes sense to you, you can move on to C++, and try to understand C++ disassembly.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/author/alex-darby/) is a low level curriculum for C/C++.